# eth0 network card cannot be detected after I purge pcscd libpcsclite1

Tags: network-interface, smartcard

I am on ubuntu 18.04 and I ran into a strange situation:
After I execute `sudo apt-get purge pcscd` and `sudo apt-get purge libpcsclite1`:

```
john@home:~/$ sudo apt-get purge pcscd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pcscd*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 167 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 175 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 190938 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pcscd (1.8.26-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
(Reading database ... 190928 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for pcscd (1.8.26-3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.38) ...
```

And then:

```
john@home:~/$ sudo apt-get purge libpcsclite1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libgif7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnome-control-center-data libnm0 libnma0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ca-certificates-java* default-jre* default-jre-headless* gnome-control-center* libpcsclite-dev* libpcsclite1* network-manager*
  network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu* network-manager-gnome* network-manager-pptp* network-manager-pptp-gnome*
  openjdk-11-jre* openjdk-11-jre-headless* openjdk-8-jre* openjdk-8-jre-headless* ubuntu-desktop* wpasupplicant*
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnome-control-center-data libnm0 libnma0
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 17 to remove and 158 not upgraded.
Need to get 886 kB of archives.
After this operation, 293 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gnome-control-center-data all 1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 [507 kB]
Get:2 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnm0 amd64 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4 [298 kB]
Get:3 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libnma0 amd64 1.8.10-2ubuntu3 [80.4 kB]
Fetched 886 kB in 0s (3,392 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 190927 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Removing default-jre (2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing openjdk-11-jre:amd64 (11.0.9.1+1-0ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Removing openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04) ...
update-alternatives: removing manually selected alternative - switching java to auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
Removing default-jre-headless (2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.417.3) ...
Removing gnome-control-center (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
Removing libpcsclite-dev (1.8.23-1) ...
Removing network-manager-gnome (1.8.10-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing network-manager-pptp-gnome (1.2.6-1) ...
Removing network-manager-pptp (1.2.6-1) ...
Removing network-manager (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing wpasupplicant (2:2.6-15ubuntu2.5) ...
Removing ca-certificates-java (20180516ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.9.1+1-0ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Removing libpcsclite1:amd64 (1.8.23-1) ...
(Reading database ... 190057 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-control-center-data_1%3a3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-control-center-data (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6) over (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libnm0_1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnm0:amd64 (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4) over (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libnma0_1.8.10-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnma0:amd64 (1.8.10-2ubuntu3) over (1.8.10-2ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Setting up libnm0:amd64 (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6) ...
No such key 'Gtk/IMModule' in schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/50_sogoupinyin.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key.
Setting up gnome-control-center-data (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libnma0:amd64 (1.8.10-2ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20201027ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

updates of cacerts keystore disabled.
done.
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
(Reading database ... 190056 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for ca-certificates-java (20180516ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for network-manager-pptp (1.2.6-1) ...
Purging configuration files for network-manager-gnome (1.8.10-2ubuntu2) ...
Purging configuration files for wpasupplicant (2:2.6-15ubuntu2.5) ...
Purging configuration files for openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64 (11.0.9.1+1-0ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Purging configuration files for network-manager (1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing network-manager, directory '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections' not empty so not removed
Purging configuration files for openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.38) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.2) ...
john@home:~/$
```

Then I tried to install the two packages of a specific version, from downloaded `.deb` files:

```
john@home:~/$ sudo dpkg -i 1804/libpcsclite1_1.8.26-3_amd64.deb 1804/pcscd_1.8.26-3_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libpcsclite1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 189980 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcsclite1_1.8.26-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcsclite1:amd64 (1.8.26-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pcscd.
Preparing to unpack 1804/pcscd_1.8.26-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pcscd (1.8.26-3) ...
Setting up libpcsclite1:amd64 (1.8.26-3) ...
Setting up pcscd (1.8.26-3) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/pcscd.socket → /lib/systemd/system/pcscd.socket.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.38) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
john@home:~/$
```

After that, I reboot the computer and the network card can no longer be detected.

What happened??
How is `pcscd` and `libpcsclite1`  related to the network interface of the computer?
How to fix it?

Comment: your **apt-get purge libpcsclite1** have removed some package related to network-manager. You can try to reinstall it,

Answer (score 0):

It seems that wpasupplicant at least [depends on having libpcsclite1 installed](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wpasupplicant), so when you remove libpcsclite1, it also removed wpasupplicant and a bunch of other networking related packages.

I would suggest re-installing all of the packages that were removed (any line beginning with "Removing") when you did `sudo apt-get purge libpcsclite1`.